# Pandas Read Irregular Data From Clipboard

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to copy data from [this CSV file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BgoJ8XsovURRvAlt7ITeQ-Gut5oVvPTe/view?usp=sharing) and read it via Pandas.read_clipboard().

I keep getting this error:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 6, saw 7
```

Is it possible to read in data like this? It works with read_csv (encoding='latin-1') but not read_clipboard.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post a few lines of the file? I can't view the link.

Comment: `df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\t', skiprows=6)` works for me.

Comment: @Allen: sorry, I had to update the link. It should work now.

Comment: @DanceParty2 Then read it in separately, using separate code. Pandas isn't a magic bullet, you cannot expect it to do everything.

Comment: @DanceParty2, unfortunately I can't access google drive files.

Comment: @Scott Boston: I used your approach without the skiprows argument (for my purposes) and it worked like a charm! Would you mind posting it as the answer so I can accept it thusly?

Comment: @DanceParty2 Will do.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use `skiprows=6` parameter, to ignore the data at the top of the file which looks like a header and not part of the core dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\t', skiprows=6)
```